# Material-ui in production css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a 'dashboard' app that uses material-ui and then inside of that dashboard I call and render other apps inside of it. This worked fine in dev but once I use a production build the material ui classnames clash and mess a bunch of stuff up.

I'm not sure what to provide here, but is there a way to apply a predecessor to css names? So I could have names like `.main-c1`, `app2-c1`, `app3-c1`, etc? Currently when I render app2 it re-writes all of the classes

Answer (score 1):

I am still pretty new to this so forgive me if it isnt the best answer. I feel like defining different themes for each app might be a helpful way to achieve the result you want.  Doing something like this

```
export default {
spacing: spacing,
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
  palette: {
    primary1Color: cyan500,
    primary2Color: cyan700,
    primary3Color: grey400,
    accent1Color: pinkA200,
    accent2Color: grey100,
    accent3Color: grey500,
    textColor: darkBlack,
    alternateTextColor: white,
    canvasColor: white,
    borderColor: grey300,
    disabledColor: fade(darkBlack, 0.3),
    pickerHeaderColor: cyan500,
    clockCircleColor: fade(darkBlack, 0.07),
    shadowColor: fullBlack,
  },
};
```

and just have different mUI themes provided when you load in your different apps when you call the theme provider.

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={YOUR-THEME-HERE}>
<AppBar title="My AppBar" />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

[mUI Theme Doc](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes)

Hope this helps at least a little bit.

Comment: The problem I'm running into is that when I render the second app it re-creates all the css (so c1 gets re-written to something completely different than before) but the old components are still there. So their css gets all out of whack. I found installing `react-jss` and wrapping each entire app in it and then using the `classNamePrefix="app1"` helped for most of the stuff. Still a little messed up though